# Iconsistent results when returning to a previous activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an android app that has various activities.

for example there is a home screen and an update screen.

The home screen is a list activity.

A button on the home screen brings you to the update screen that updates the database from a server. In theory when Returning to teh homescreen after an update, the list should be changed to reflect the update just done.

the code for going to the update screen is as follows:

```
Button synch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.synchButton);
    synch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View viewParam) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, SynchScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and the code for returning back to the homescreen after the updates is:

```
main_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View viewParam) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

the list is compiled from an async task that runs in onStart, so my understanding is that onStart should run when I return to the homescreen, thus always displaying the most up to date version of the list.

On my Emulator I always get teh updated list, but when I run it on my phone the list is never updated, it just returns to the state of teh screen before I did the update.

any ideas?

thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) section of the Android documentation. The code updating the view should probably be moved to onResume, since the Activity might not get killed when launching a new one.

Comment: Thanks, such an obvious mistake.. you got there first so this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put the code for starting the `Asynctask` in `onResume`. Read the documentation related to activity life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
Apaptor.refreshListView(Vector);    
}
```